# mysql ERROR: Util.checkForServerUpgrade: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket

Tags: mysql, mysql-shell

I run on my server mysql in version 5.7.40

```
mysql --version
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.40, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
```

And generally it works without any issues. I want to upgrade from 5.7.40 to 8.*.* and because of it I want to use mysql tools to check if it is safe to upgrade. But every time I run command

```
mysqlsh -- util checkForServerUpgrade root@localhost
```

I got following error

```
Cannot set LC_ALL to locale en_US.UTF-8: No such file or directory
Please provide the password for 'root@localhost': **********
ERROR: Util.checkForServerUpgrade: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like socket not there in the default directory (/tmp/mysql.sock)

Try this with port

mysqlsh -- util checkForServerUpgrade root@localhost:3306

OR

Using proper Socket

mysqlsh --socket=/tmp/mysql.sock --user=root -e "util.checkForServerUpgrade()"